# Physically override linux credentials

Tags: linux, security, password, pam, passwd

Say someone gains physical access to my computer, and they want to login to my account and see everything I have. Is it possible that they take the hard-drive out of my computer, modify the file `/etc/shadow` with a new password, and then use it to login?

In other words, does the Linux password change by simply modifying `/etc/shadow`?

(All this assuming that there's no HD volume-encryption involved)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once they have the hard disk drive they hardly need your password. They simply mount all partitions according to (your) `/etc/fstab`. The next step is `sudo su - "your account id"` (if your id is 501, just `sudo su - 501`).

Short on using encrypted disk with a good password and all, there is little if any you can do to make your data safe.

This "little" include:

- Do not use plain text password in scripts (for instance a cron job collecting email (`...=pop("me@google.com","avreyclverpassword")`, access to remote hosts, etc.)
- Do not use password-less **gpg** and **ssh** keys. (Re-type them each time or use an agent to store them in memory.)

Answer (score 3):

If no encryption is involved then yes.

But if it is possible to boot from CD or USB, they could just boot from a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD)/USB flash drive, mount your hard-drive and read everything.

And even if booting from CD/USB is prohibited/impossible, they would just take your drive and mount it in another computer.

Modifying your password isn't necessary. They don't have to log in as you. They just need the right permissions. And if they can be root, then they can read anything that isn't encrypted.